# magento is not showing cart products on just categories and product pages

Tags: magento, cart

Magento cart showing products on cart and main page correctly, but it is showing empty cart on categories and product pages, actually cart is not empty.
My site is `dressat.se` any help would be appreciated. I am searching it from previous 2 days.

Comment: This question better belongs on [MageOverflow](https://magento.stackexchange.com) because it is not a coding question but a question specific to how Magento works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) Run the Magento Compiler to check the changes. 
2) Clear the Magento Cache through magento admin panel. 
3) Check the product is enabled.
4) Check the product stock item. 
5) Check the product quantity.
```

Once all the things are correctly set, Run the `Index Management` in though admin panel

This will help you.

Comment: I have done all 5 steps and reindex data, but still cart products are not showing on some pages. Is there any other solution? Thanks

Comment: You server is shared hosting or running under the dedicated server ?

Comment: I am running dedicated server,

Comment: Restart your server services using SSH to check the page again .

Comment: But my hosting does not Provide SSH service, Do you know any other solution?